# How to change to constant interpolation mode from a python script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have written a python script to create an animation out of a file containing the trajectory of some objects and **I would like to switch to a constant mode of interpolation** (I have one position per time step and other interpolation modes are really slow and not necessary in this case). The code is launched in the 3D view context.

I have put the following code:

```
area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type
area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.graph.select_all_toggle()
bpy.ops.graph.interpolation_type(type='CONSTANT')
area.type = old_type
```

but it does nothing...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

**slightly simple option** (probably not the best in the long run)

A toggle inverts, if all curves are selected it will select the curves that are not selected. The solution might be as simple as this.

```
bpy.ops.graph.select_all_toggle(invert=False)
```

**broader answer** (which is hopefully more useful)

Easy enough, but perhaps not very obvious.

```
kf = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].animation_data.action.fcurves[0].keyframe_points[0]
kf.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
```

or for *Keyframes* on all *F-Curves* of that object

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
fcurves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
for fcurve in fcurves:
    for kf in fcurve.keyframe_points:
        kf.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
```

Without seeing your code I can only assume things about it. You can use the Outliner (DataBlocks view) to get a reasonable idea of where to look in the API for these things.

[image]

**Addendum**

If the script seems to behave slowly, it might not be the interpolation but the way the script adds keyframes. I Might be wrong but I assume you are using something like this to add keyframes:

```
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='Location', confirm_success=True)
# this does more than just add keyframes
```

This would be faster:

```
import bpy

positions = (0,0,2),(0,1,2),(3,2,1),(3,4,1),(1,2,1)
start_pos = (0,0,0)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=32, size=0.3, location=start_pos)
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
ob = bpy.context.active_object

frame_num = 0

for position in positions:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    ob.location = position
    ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)  # <-- this
    frame_num += 10
```

Setting the interpolation type at creation time:

```
for position in positions:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    ob.location = position
    ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)

    for fcurve in ob.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        kf = fcurve.keyframe_points[-1]
        kf.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
    frame_num += 10
```